# Can a virus infiltrate an empty (new) usb stick?

Tags: malware

If it can, then how much time does the virus need in order to corrupt the usb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virus can put an `autorun.inf`-File on the usb stick so that next time you plug it in somewhere, it will automatically get executed (on some versions of Windows, anyway). This takes only the amount of time needed to transfer the file to the stick.

It can also make the USB Stick bootable and write itself into the boot loader code in the hopes that the stick will be left connected to the computer and the next time the computer is started, it might boot from the stick. Depending on how the stick is formatted, this can be nearly instantaneous or take considerable time.

Finally, the virus can copy itself to the stick as a normal executable file and give itself an interesting name in the hopes that you'll be intrigued and double-click on it. Since many USB sticks get delivered with some form of encryption software (so they're not really empty when you buy them), the virus might pose as such software or hide itself inside it.